# Как реализовать добавление товаров в корзину и оформление заказа в drf?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-orm, cart

Не могу понять как реализовать корзину в drf. Понял пока, что нужно это делать через сессии. Но конкретно(на практике) не понимаю как это сделать. Нужно ли создавать отдельное приложение cart?

Comment: Приветствую, вы - новый участник, потому советую вам изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем. Большой плюс - то что вы уже начали изучать проблему, но, думаю, будет ещё лучше, если вы поделитесь с нами источниками информации, что на которые вы полагаетесь, это может помочь ответить на наш вопрос!